# How to process Estimator categorical_column when request tensorflow-model-server?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

As you known, request Tensorflow-serving server need organize request data format like this structure:

```
Example(
    features=Features(
        feature={
            'SepalLength': Feature(float_list=FloatList(value=[5.1])),
            'SepalWidth': Feature(float_list=FloatList(value=[3.3])),
            'PetalLength': Feature(float_list=FloatList(value=[1.7])),
            'PetalWidth': Feature(float_list=FloatList(value=[0.5])),
        }
    )
)
```

if my data only `tf.feature_column.numeric_column`, that's easy, i can process like this:

```
tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))
```

but my training data like is :

```
categorical_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_identity(
            key = name, num_buckets = 3 )
indicator_column = tf.feature_column.indicator_column( categorical_column )
```

it's `categorical_column`, like some kind of one hot structure, in this situation, i don't know how to handle this, and i can't find any advanced tutorials to handle this,

How should i do if i want to process my data to adapt `tensorflow-model-server`
 request requirement ? thanks.

PS: 
i use components below:
training framework:
`tensorflow estimator`
client:
`tensorflow-seving-api`
server:
`tensorflow-model-server`

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira invite

Comment: @ursak hi, invite

Comment: hi, @paweł-szczur

Comment: @fematich hello